# Where can I find the API documentation for older versions of Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-v6

**Where can I find the API documentation for older versions of Highcharts ?**

Answer (score 1):

As per this thread https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40799 in their forum you can use this url format but many (probably most) of the versions doesn't contain an API folder where to see the documentation.

Luckily I found this one https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/6.0.5/ which holds docs close enough for the version I was interested in.